# Issue with 'Plates Field Type

Tags: add-on, fieldtype

I'm running into an issue with the 'Plates field type. The site is running EE v2.5.5. When I select a layout, the selection doesn't "stick". It appears to when I select it, but when I save the entry, and come back in to edit it, the field appears as though nothing has been selected. Has anyone run into this issue before? If so, were you able to find a fix for it? I would appreciate any ideas you would be willing to share!

**What the field looks like when I create an entry**

[image: Choose a Layout Field]

**What the field looks like when I select the layout type**

[image]

**What the field looks like when I return to edit the entry**

[image]

Comment: I've had this numerous times, Are you using Structure, if so, is the Structure template field prior to the Plates one?  Have you viewed the Template Manager (refreshed the list), then gone in to the field type setup for Plates and ensured that the templates are correctly assigned to your layout types? The scenario you're seeing happens mainly when the template assigned to the layout isn't matching the template for the entry.

Comment: @PeterLewis thanks for the response. I am not using Structure on this site. I've synchronized all of the templates and checked to make sure the assigned layout is matching the template of the entry. Still no dice. I'll keep trying different things!

Comment: There's no straight answer I'm afraid, the cause is most definitely that the plates value saved isnt matching the template. Are you using the latest version of Plates (as I seem to recall a bug similar to this in an early version). Also inspect the html and see what the value is for the plates field. Do you have the Pages module active? Do you have the pages URI field above the Plates field?